# How do I "click" accept using requests in Python

Tags: python, python-requests

Here is the html that I am looking to "click"

```
<input id="ctl00_mainContentPlaceHolder_acceptButton" name="ctl00$mainContentPlaceHolder$acceptButton" type="submit" value="I accept the above terms"/>
```

The general template that I am using is

```
import requests

url = 'SOME WEBSITE'

data = {'button': 'click'}
r = requests.post(url, params=data)
```

How do I specifically use request to click this one? I tried a few combinations but all failed.
Example: `data = {'ctl00$mainContentPlaceHolder$acceptButton': 'submit'}`
returns with r.content

```
b'<html>\r\n<body>\r\n\xc2\xa0\r\n<script type="text/javascript">\r\n\xc2\xa0\xc2\xa0 window.location = "/SecurityResponse/?SupportID=4623646759448296673";\r\n</script>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>'
```

Comment: You should use [Selenium](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/) instead.

Answer (score 1):

You should use Selenium to do this, something like that:

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = '/Library/ApplicationSupport/Google/chromedriver')
browser.get('https://...')

example = browser.find_element_by_xpath("...")
# Or
example = browser.find_element_by_id("I accept the above terms")

example.click()
```